# Excel VBA failing to access CorelDraw Page property with Late Binding

Tags: excel, vba, late-binding, office-2016, coreldraw

I have an Excel (Office 16) VBA code that opens a CorelDraw document and performs a task based on the orientation of each page in the document. The code is as follows:

```
Dim app As Object
Dim page As Object

Set app = CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application")
app.OpenDocument "xxx.pdf"

For Each page In app.ActiveDocument.Pages
If page.Orientation = cdrLandscape Then
...
End If
Next
```

The code fails to execute the "If" statement, even though I can see the orientation property of the page in the Locals window. What is wrong here? (late binding is a necessary condition in this case)

Comment: Excel doesn't know `cdrLandscape` so is creating a variable of that name with default value 0.  Replace it with its intended value of 1 [See here](https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/20/e/cdrpageorientation?lang=cs).  Note: adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your module would alert you to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`cdrLandscape` needs to be declared in your code if you're using late binding, or you can substitute the numeric value (1)